# Undefined Symbol for Architecture Upon building project and calling LLVM

Tags: c, clang, llvm

LLVM Release Version: 14.0.1

LLVM Version:clang+llvm-14.0.1-x86_64-apple-darwin.tar.xz

Upon running `cmake --build build` the output is as follows:

```
[ 18%] Linking CXX executable wplc
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "typeinfo for llvm::cl::GenericOptionValue", referenced from:
      typeinfo for llvm::cl::OptionValueCopy<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > in wplc.cpp.o
      typeinfo for llvm::cl::OptionValueCopy<bool> in wplc.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to [edit] your questions to improve them, like for example actually asking a question.

Comment: Looks like C++ not C.